# Average price per Cluster

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions

I'm testing this code.

```
SELECT ID, Cluster, Date, Price,
    AVG(Price) OVER (PARTITION BY Cluster ORDER BY Date ROWS BETWEEN 171 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) As ClusterAverage
FROM tblCluster
WHERE LEN(ID) = 9 AND IDNOT LIKE '%[^a-Z0-9]%'
   AND Cluster in ('430.00')
```

I was thinking I would get one average price for ClusterAverage.  I thought that's what the `'PARTITION BY Cluster'` does.  Instead, I get this.

```
ID          Cluster Date        Price       ClusterAverage
50064FAL8   430     6/14/2019   115.5827    115.5827
50064FAL8   430     6/17/2019   115.694     115.63835
50064FAL8   430     6/19/2019   116.5761    115.9509333
50064FAL8   430     6/21/2019   116.1692    116.0055
50064FAL8   430     6/25/2019   117.2248    116.24936
50064FAL8   430     6/27/2019   117.0839    116.38845
50064FAL8   430     6/28/2019   117.0156    116.4780429
50064FAL8   430     6/30/2019   118.2286    116.6968625
```

In this case, I just have one ID and one Cluster, but in most cases I will have multiple ID numbers within one single cluster.  Finally, I'm going back 171 days because I can have up to 171 days of data per ID, but it can be a lot less, like less than 10 days of data per ID.  I wonder if harcoding this as 171 is the way to do it, or some kind of count-max-days per ID.

Comment: What is the actual result set you want? It almost sounds like you just need a simple non-windowing AVG() aggregation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is, your average is computed over the rolling 171 last rows, so it changes for every row.

I think that you want a *filter* on the date in the `WHERE` clause and an `OVER()` without `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT 
    ID, 
    Cluster, 
    Date, 
    Price,
    AVG(Price) OVER (PARTITION BY Cluster) As ClusterAverage
FROM tblCluster
WHERE 
    LEN(ID) = 9 
    AND ID NOT LIKE '%[^a-Z0-9]%'
    AND Cluster in ('430.00')
    AND Date > DATEADD(day, 171, getdate())
```

If you need more fine-grained control over the date range over which the average is computed, you can also use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT 
    ID, 
    Cluster, 
    Date, 
    Price,
    AVG(CASE WHEN Date > DATEADD(day, 10, getdate()) THEN Price END) 
        OVER (PARTITION BY Cluster) As ClusterAverageLast10Days,
    AVG(CASE WHEN Date > DATEADD(day, 20, getdate()) THEN Price END) 
        OVER (PARTITION BY Cluster) As ClusterAverageLast20Days,
    AVG(Price) OVER (PARTITION BY Cluster) As ClusterAverageOverall
FROM tblCluster
WHERE 
    LEN(ID) = 9 
    AND ID NOT LIKE '%[^a-Z0-9]%'
    AND Cluster in ('430.00')
    AND Date > DATEADD(day, 171, getdate())
```

Comment: Maybe I didn't describe the ask as well as I should have, but I think you nailed it GMB!!  It's late for me now.  I'm going to take a closer look tomorrow.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is a rolling average of the Price.

The windowing function is looking at all the Rows "Preceding" the current row. Hence the first row in the output is the same as the Price, the second is the average of the first 2 etc.

I think what you need is to create a CTE that averages the Price over each cluster (and ID if needed) and then `JOIN` that back on the ID and cluster

Answer (score 0):

Add partition by ID TO existing partitioned Cluster as

```
Partition by ID, CLUSTER..
```

As you said the data has id wise clustering as well you could add this id as above to result the same. The average now returned would be an idwise clustering row average

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you are looking for is a simple average grouped up at ID and cluster level. If so:

```
SELECT ID, Cluster,
    AVG(Price) as ClusterAverage
FROM tblCluster
WHERE LEN(ID) = 9 AND IDNOT LIKE '%[^a-Z0-9]%' AND Date>DATEADD(day,-171,GETDATE())
GROUP BY ID, Cluster
```